# Capitalize journal name in latex

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

I have a `sample.bib` with a `main.tex` as below, using  [Chicago Style](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/the-chicago-citation-style-with-biblatex/pdqqrmwtdqpc). I was wondering if there is a way to see the journal's name with all capital letters `American Review` rather than `American review`, without changing `sample.bib` by hand. Many thanks in advance.

main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{sample}

\begin{document}
\title{The Chicago Citation Style with biblatex}
\author{WriteLaTeX}
\maketitle

\section{Demonstration}

 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \autocite{PP95} Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

sample.bib

```
@article{PP95,
  author = "Adam Parusi\'nski and Piotr Pragacz",
   title = "A formula for the {E}uler characteristic of singular hypersurfaces",
 journal = "American review",
  volume = 4,
    year = 1995,
   pages = "337-351"}
```

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] to your question, so that we can replicate the problem without having to go to external websites and make guesses what or what not you might have in your code.

Comment: ... a [mre] would also clear the confusion of using both the bibtex and biblatex tags ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `mfirstuc` package and adjust the field format like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\DeclareFieldFormat{jtnoformat}{\capitalisewords{#1}}

\begin{document}
\title{The Chicago Citation Style with biblatex}
\author{WriteLaTeX}
\maketitle

\section{Demonstration}

 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \autocite{PP95} Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

(please note that in biblatex you should use `\addbibressource` instead of `\bibliography`)

Comment: this is fantastic <3