# Capitalize journal title for apa in Latex

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

I am using overleaf to put together my references that follow the apa 7th edition. The journal titles however are not capitalized. How do I correct that? Note that I tried the method suggested in this post [Capitalize journal name in latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72032922/capitalize-journal-name-in-latex) but it didn't work for me.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa,uniquename=false,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{golinkoff1979comparison} said this 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

My `refs.bib` here

```
@article{golinkoff1979comparison,
  title={A comparison of fathers' and mothers' speech with their young children},
  author={Golinkoff, Roberta Michnick and Ames, Gail Johnson},
  journal={Child development},
  pages={28--32},
  year={1979},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
```

The reference prints this:
[image]

This is a cross post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670231/capitalize-journal-title-for-apa-in-latex

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/670231/36296

Answer (score 1):

Same method as in the post you linked to:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\title{text}
\shorttitle{short title}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa,uniquename=false,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{golinkoff1979comparison,
  title={A comparison of fathers' and mothers' speech with their young children},
  author={Golinkoff, Roberta Michnick and Ames, Gail Johnson},
  journal={Child development},
  pages={28--32},
  year={1979},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\capitalisewords{#1}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{golinkoff1979comparison} said this 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]